# Unknown error compiling opencv framework: Undefined symbols: "_CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL"

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, gcc

Xcode is giving me the following error, I don't really know what to do, is driving my crazy.
I'm importing an OpenCV framework so maybe the problem is there or something related to the compiler.
Could anyone tell me what to do or search for?

```
      Undefined symbols:   "_CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL", referenced from:
      cv::ImageIOEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)in OpenCV(grfmt_imageio.o)   "_CGImageDestinationAddImage", referenced from:
      cv::ImageIOEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)in OpenCV(grfmt_imageio.o)   "_CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex", referenced from:
      cv::ImageIODecoder::readHeader()      in OpenCV(grfmt_imageio.o)   "_CGImageDestinationFinalize", referenced from:
      cv::ImageIOEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)in OpenCV(grfmt_imageio.o)   "_CGImageSourceCreateWithURL", referenced from:
      cv::ImageIODecoder::readHeader()      in OpenCV(grfmt_imageio.o) ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: How are you importing the framework?

Comment: This is **not** a **Compilation error** It is **Linking error** the linker is telling you it cannot link to some symbol names that you are using.Check library paths etc.

Comment: Agreed linker error not compiler. quartz.lib?

Comment: Ok I solve the problem, the library I was trying to import had some dependencies so I just import the librays and all is working.

Comment: For more information it was "ImageIO.framework"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just for sake of future visitors (like me ;-)), I report the Gustavo self-answer:

Add 
       "**ImageIO.framework**" 
to 
       "**Linked Frameworks and Library**"