# How can I find which library I am missing when I compile my Objective-C++ code?

Tags: c++, xcode, objective-c++

Sometime, I encounter an error like this:

[Unknown error compiling opencv framework: Undefined symbols: "_CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725100/unknown-error-compiling-opencv-framework)

I got exactly the same error, after I linked with ImageIO.framework, everything solved. But how can I know the missing framework is the ImageIO? Is there any technique to find out? Or can Xcode help me to find out?

Comment: It's not an "unknown error", it's "undefined symbols error". Doing a search for the missing symbols might be a good start.

Comment: Undefined symbol is simply the compiler telling you that it needs a definition of the symbol. The ImageIO.framework provided this definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely to the error message, you will find out that xcode is telling you what is missing.

```
Undefined symbols: "_CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL", referenced from: 
cv::ImageIOEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector > const&)
in OpenCV(grfmt_imageio.o)
```

Ok, first search for a listed undefined symbols like: -CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL. Then look at the headerfile of the class were the undefined symbol comes from. for CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL it is CGImageDestination.h. look at the top of the headerfile and check if you have all of the frameworks which they import. in your case it's `#include <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>`and `#include <ImageIO/CGImageSource>` and another ImageIO import. this should tell you that you have to import the CoreGraphics framework and the ImageIO framework.

Comment: How can I know that the `ImageIOEncoder` is from `ImageIO.framework`?

Comment: I like to use the `mdfind` command for this. There is probably something built into Xcode nowadays though, but I never bothered to find out :)

Comment: @DNB5brims symbol prefix is often the name of the framework.